# Updating a table with a sum of another table throws Incorrect number of bindings supplied error

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I created a refresh database button in my web/flask form, but when I try to refresh, I get this error message:

> sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The
> current statement uses 0, and there are 1 supplied.

I tried all the various combinations in **cursor.execute(query, (database,))** but I just couldn't figure out how to fix it...

```
#refresh portfolio stats
@app.route('/refresh', methods = ['GET','POST'])
def refresh():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        database = "data.sqlite"
        connection = sql.connect(database)

        query = ''' UPDATE
                    portfolio_table
                    SET
                    portfolio_cost_total = (SELECT SUM(product_cost_total)
                                            FROM product_table)
                    WHERE
                    portfolio_table.portfolio_id = '1' '''

        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute(query, (database,))

        db.session.commit()
        #df = pd.read_sql_query(query, connection)
        #df.head()

    return redirect(url_for('index'))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"bindings" are the [placedholders in a query](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.execute). There are no placeholders in `query` (either `?` or `:name`), but parameters are being sent to the execute call ie `(database, )`.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm genuinely lost here, I went through the documentation and still don't understand how to rearrange the code...
how can I fix this, please?

Comment: Why are you sending `(database, )` as a parameter? It appears to be the database name in the connect call. It has no place in the query. The query does not use parameters, don't send parameters.

Comment: ok, I changed that part with:

        *cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute(query)
        db.session.commit()*

I no longer have an error but nothing happens...

Comment: that's something completely different. "Nothing happens" is not descriptive enough. This error is "fixed", so keep digging and post another question if necessary.